# renaming and saving in NSDocumentsDirectory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Its like this, in my app, I have a `UIScrollView` on it is a thumbnail view, they are images from my `NSCachesDirectory`. 
I saved them from my picker then named them in my array like: `images0.png,images.1.png`... etc

So for example I have images in my directory this way : `images0.png, images1.png, images2.png, images3.png`.

Then I delete images1.png, the remaining images will be like this : `images0.png,images2.png, images3.png` right?

What I wanted to achieve is get the images in `NSDocumentsDirectory` then renamed them AGAIN or sort them again like `images0.png, images1.png, images2.png`...etc again?
is this possible? hope you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this **NSFileManger moveItemAtPath:  toPath:  error:**  but you should supply the **toPath:same_path_but_different_filename**. This moves the file to a new path with new file name that you provide. [see this](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/09/rename-file-in-nsdocumentdirectory.html)

Since it seems you want the whole logic to rename your images file, here is the code you can try provided the files are in the Document directory

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * oldPath =[[NSString alloc]init];
NSString * newPath =[[NSString alloc]init];

int count=0;
for (int i=0; i<=[[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil]count]; i++) {

    oldPath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%d.png",i]];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:oldPath]) {

        newPath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"images%d.png",count]];
        [fileManager moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:nil]; 
        count+=1;

    }

}
```

Comment: I have added a link, was that helpful?

Comment: Ya it can be. Are you seeking for the logic to do the whole renaming thing?

Comment: yes, i am. this really is my problem. getting the images in the directory then renaming them.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesnot allow renameing of file saved. So alternative is to get all contents at document directory like this:

```
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:yourDocDirPath error:NULL];
```

Now sort like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending: YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
     return [obj1 compare: obj2 options: NSNumericSearch];
 }];

NSArray * sortedDirectoryContent = [directoryContent sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor]];
```

We have sorted array rewrite all files with new name:

```
for(NSString *fileName in sortedDirectoryContent)
{
  NSString *filePath = [yourDocDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
  NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];

    if(fileData)
    {
        NSString *newFilePath = [yourDocDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"New Name here"];
        [fileData writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES];
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if(fileData)
    {
        NSString *newFilePath = [yourDocDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"New Name here"];
        [fileData writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES];
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: i have different named images in my directory.

Comment: can i put my code for saving and loading in nsdocu, could you help me convert to the `for(NSString *fileName in sortedDirectoryContent)` ?